# Is there any way to view media files in template in django?

Tags: python-3.7, django-2.2, webfaction

I deployed my project to web faction, set the static and media settings. Initially media files not showing, only the static files are shown in the site. But I can see the media files in my local system.

I used filefield not imagefield during model creation. Is that a problem?
is tried both ways:

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{i.cover_image.url}}" alt="">

<img src="{{i.cover_image.url}}" alt="">
```

These are settings:

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/{}/webapps/testapp_static/'.format('user')
STATIC_FILE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL= '/media/'
```

And i added this setting to myproject urls
urls.py

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Please help me where i went wrong. Is there any additional settings or path is missing. i want to view media files in my template.

Answer (score 0):

I Put MEDIA_URL ='http://www.yoursite.com/static/' in Settings.py file and in template i used

```
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ obj.image.url }}" >
```

now its working properly in production. For local, change media url to /media/.